# How do I kill a PowerShell script that is invoked from a Python GUI?

Tags: python, powershell

How do I kill a PowerShell script that is invoked from a Python GUI? Once the script is executed, I get an empty Powershell window.

I have been adding cmdlets such as "exit" and "Stop-Process -Name powershell" with no success to my script. Also, the script's only purpose is to add a printer to my device.

### Python script

[My Python Script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gHB5.png)

### Powershell Script with Blank Window

[Blank PS Window with script that is being run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3hNk.png)

The script successfully adds the printer, however this annoying PS window stays on my screen.

Comment: What are those apostrophes doing escaped into the name of the script you are trying to run? I think you aren't actually running a script, because those aren't valid filenames, so you're getting a powershell window opened and then it will sit there waiting for you to tell it to do something.

BTW, actually copying the text into your question would be much more likely to get you useful answers.  Screen grabs really don't work here.

Comment: Actually I see that Powershell itself apparently ignores the spurious quotes and semicolon, but still best not to put them in as Python will be escaping your command line arguments for you so you want to pass unescaped strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why you are appending double quotes at the end of your string. This should work:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName \\...
Stop-Process -Name "powershell*"
```

Tested & working on PSV5.

Comment: Hello Jelphy. After using the "stop process" cmlet that you provded, the blank PS window unfortunately still stays on my screen.

Comment: Strange. In a separate PowerShell prompt, can you see the ID of the process when the blank window is open? `Get-Process -Name "PowerShell"`

Comment: Yes, I am able to see the ID through another prompt. When the script is run, I am not able to interact or type anything into the PS window that pops up.

Comment: What about this? `$p = Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "powershell*"}` `Stop-Process -ID $p.ID` worked for me

Comment: Hello. I was able to exit out of everything including all my opened web pages using this script. I was able to have the window exit by adding the        -AsJob parameter to my PS script. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

After your PowerShell statement you can add a semicolon and an exit command.

For example, "...Powershell.exe... ; exit"

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried command + d?

Comment: Sorry, I should clarify. I have a Python Script/ GUI that runs PowerShell. My issue is that I need the PowerShell window to close out after the script is run.

Comment: So button on Python GUI is pressed > PowerShell is opened via Python script > PowerShell script is run, then the window won't go away. I also cannot use my python GUI until PS window is closed out. Thank you Neli!